# Get part-Of class from OWL Ontology

Tags: java, owl-api, hermit

I have an ontology made with protègè, I defined an `ObjectProperty` named part-Of. 
[image]

I'm parsing an `OWLClass` trying to find out whether or not the subclasses are `part-Of` the parsed class. In this case, I am parsing `At_Home` when the subclasses, `ANA` and `PHE`, have the following `subclass of` signature as in this picture
[image]
I've already tried with:

```
OWLDataFactory df = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLObjectProperty partOf = df.getOWLObjectProperty("part-Of");
    OWLClassExpression c = df.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(partOf, target);
    NodeSet<OWLClass> subClasses = hermit.getSubClasses(c, true);
    if(subClasses.isEmpty()) {
        //System.out.println("\tQuesta classe non ha parti");
        res[0] = null;
    }
    else {
        for(Node<OWLClass> parte : subClasses) {
            risultato.add(parte.getRepresentativeElement().getIRI().getFragment());
        }
        res[0] = risultato;
    }
```

where `target` is the `At_Home` `OWLClass`, but the method continues to return an empty `NodeSet`, so it means that `At_Home` has no parts even if `ANA` and `PHE` are its parts.
The wanted result should be a `NodeSet` with the `OWLClass` "ANA" and "PHE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `df.getOWLObjectProperty("part-Of");`

This is the problem. You need to use the full IRI of your property, not just the fragment; this won't match the property as stated in your ontology.

Comment: so adding the full IRI "semanticweb.org/diego/ontologies/2019/2/…" should do the trick, but how can I get it from ontology that I didn't create myself? I mean, in the IRI there is "diego" and parts like "2019/2" which are variable, how can I find the right ObjectProperty with only the fragment name? is there a way? @Ignazio

Comment: I don't really understand the question. In any ontology, whether created by you or imported from some other site, the properties are identified by absolute IRIs, not relative ones. In which scenario do you only have the fragment name?